# ncalc thousands comma formatted fails to evaluate?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ncalc

I am currently using ncalc library to do several evaluation and get the result out of it.

Right now I have found a problem where if I have a price in the format "1,234.01" it will fail to evaluate my expression.

The current workaround I've used was to remove the `,` but I was wondering if there is way to evaluate a currency without having to remove the `,` for example:

```
decimal price = 0;
if (!decimal.TryParse(iPrice.Text, out price))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Price is not formatted correctly...");
    return;
}

decimal currency = 0;
if (!decimal.TryParse(iCurrency.Text, out currency))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Currency is not formatted correctly...");
    return;
}

string formula = iFormula.Text.Replace("Price", price.ToString("n2")).Replace("Currency", currency.ToString("n2"));
Expression exp = new Expression(formula);
exp.Evaluate();
```

Evaluate fails because of the `,` from my price where if I remove it, it works just fine.

Sample of the formula:

```
(((Price+12,9)+((Price+12,9)*0,05)+(((Price+12,9)+((Price+12,9)*0,05))*0,029)+0,45)*Currency)
```

Stacktrace as requested:

```
NCalc.EvaluationException was unhandled
  Message=mismatched input ',' expecting ')' at line 1:4
mismatched input ',' expecting ')' at line 1:20
mismatched input ',' expecting ')' at line 1:43
mismatched input ',' expecting ')' at line 1:59
missing EOF at ')' at line 1:77
  Source=NCalc
  StackTrace:
       at NCalc.Expression.Evaluate()
```

Comment: Sounds like a Culture issue, or ncalc does not support anything but the default invariant culture.

Comment: leppie good call I will check invariant...

Comment: Given the stacktrace. It is surely a culture issue.

Comment: Using Invariant doesn't seem to fix it either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is still unclear to me, but I *suspect* you can fix this just by changing the format you're using when replacing. Change this:

```
string formula = iFormula.Text.Replace("Price", price.ToString("n2")) 
                              .Replace("Currency", currency.ToString("n2"));
```

to this:

```
string formula = iFormula.Text.Replace("Price", price.ToString("f2")) 
                              .Replace("Currency", currency.ToString("f2"));
```

That will use the "fixed point" format instead of the "number" format. You won't get grouping. Note that grouping isn't part of the number itself - it's part of how you *format* a number.

I'd also be tempted to specify the invariant culture explicitly, by the way.

As an aside: I haven't used NCalc myself, but if it's really forcing you to specify the numeric values in an expression as *text*, that sounds pretty poor. I'd expect some sort of parameterization (as per most SQL providers, for example) which should make all of this go away.

Comment: Yes that solves it using `f2` instead... Now I understood what you were trying to tell me on the other answer's comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have a separator in your decimal literal. The compiler will confuse it with declaring multiple variables with the same type like:

```
decimal price = 1m, tax = 234m;
```

If it was a string, however, you could parse it like:

```
decimal price = Decimal.Parse("1,234.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT: my answer above was directed to the code sample in the first version of the question. Now that the question has been edited:**

You can control the string representation of your decimal values using the `Decimal.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)` method overload. This allows you to specify a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) format string. In your case, it sounds like you need to have 2 decimal digits separated using a dot, and no group separators (no commas). So you could say:

```
price.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) // ex. result: "1234.56"
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is important if you need a dot separator regardless of the current culture. If you don't specify that, the output could be "1234,56" depending on the current culture (e.g. in case of european cultures like de-DE, or fr-FR).

Comment: price and currency are set by the user on a text box and I am using decimal.TryParse to convert into decimal, the above decimal values were mere samples to expose my issue.

Comment: @leppie do you see the statement: `decimal price = 1,123.01m;` ?

Comment: @Guapo You didn't mention that in the Q. Your current code sample is trying to assign a decimal using a literal that includes a comma. And you say "it works when I remove the comma". My answer is directed to your question _as is_. If you edit your question, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Guapo: So where does it actually fail? At parsing time, or in the expression? It's *really* important to make that clear, as it sounds like you may have actually removed all of the *useful* code in your question, replacing it with invalid code...

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: You are talking about the C# compiler, while the OP is passing text to ncalc's interpreter.

Comment: @JonSkeet it fails at the expression ONLY when the price contains a comma like I explained above, so I don't see where I have removed anything here, I am just posting the relevant information related to it. In fact its a brand new project with barely nothing on it but 4 labels, 1 button, 3 text box (1 for price, 1 for currency, 1 for the formula).

Comment: @Guapo: You removed the parsing. By the time a value has been parsed, *it doesn't contain a comma*. If the parsing of everything that contains a comma happens *before* the expression, then it's very unclear what the problem is. (Although it's all confused by the way you're then formatting `price` again... why?) If it's the parsing of the *expression itself* that's the problem (where again, you've got commas) it's worth knowing that. Basically, there are two places where commas could occur: in your expression or in the values. You haven't made it clear which you care about.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think we are understanding each other, I have a text box with let's say `1,123.01`, then I parse it and have the `decimal price` all good right ? Now I want to replace on my formula where I have the TEXT `Price` with my `decimal price`, so I am using the above replace which turns the decimal into a string with 2 decimal places but then again when that value is on the thousands it will contain a comma, which breaks the expression. And as what I think is a dirty workaround I am using another replace to remove that comma which I don't want to.

Comment: @Guapo: My point is that the fact that the *textbox* has a comma in it is completely irrelevant. After parsing, there's no sign of that comma. You're getting a comma in your *expression* because of the format string you're using - you'd get it even if the textbox just contained "1123.01". See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: @Guapo so the line `decimal price = 1,123.01m;` doesn't exist in your code. Instead, you have a decimal variable `price` and you pass that variable to `TryParse`, correct?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Like I mentioned on my 2nd comment of your answer, those were mere to represent the issue.

Comment: @Guapo when you were presenting the issue, you introduced another unrelated code error, and I answered to that error. In order to avoid the same confusion for other readers, you should edit the code sample and remove that line of code, or change it like: `decimal price = Decimal.Parse("1,234.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` Not trying to argue, just trying to improve your question.